# PYTHON : Simple random generation driving if/else

Tags: python, if-statement, xrange

new to programmation, im learning and here is probably a very simple problem for you guy.

```
import random

def run_stair_yes():
    print "\nRunning in stairs is very dangerous!"
    print "Statistique shows that you have 70% chance of falling"
    print "\nroll the dice!"


    for i in xrange(1):
        print random.randint(1, 100)

    if i <= 70 :
        print "\nWell, gravity is a bitch. You fell and die."

    elif i >= 71 :
        athlethic()

    else: 
            print "im boned!"
            exit(0)
```

my problem is that, whatever number is generated, it's always giving me the same "gravity is a bitch. You fell and die".

where do i go wrong ?

Comment: tanxs all, i took all your comments in account and made a simpler code. It's working.

Comment: the `else` bloc is unnecessary as your function well never not evaluate true for both i <= 70 and i >= 70 IF you assign i to a random number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never actually set i to the `random.randint()`

You say

```
for i in xrange(1):
```

Where i takes the value of `0` as you iterate through the `xrange(1)` and then you just print out the result of `random.randint(1, 100)`, not assigning it to i.

Try this

```
i = random.randint(1, 100)
```

Answer (score 6):

Additionally to jamylak's advice, some general pointers to improve your code:

- Multi-line prompts are better written using the triple-quoted string syntax instead of multiple `print` statements. That way you only need to write `print` once, and you don't need all those extra newline characters (`\n`)

Example:

```
print """
Running on the stairs is dangerous!

You have a 70% chance to fall.

Run on the stairs anyway?
"""
```

- Your probability calculation uses random integers in the range [1-100], but it's probably more natural to use a floating point number. (Either way will work.)
- You don't need to check if the number is `<= 70` and then check if it's `>= 71`. By definition (for integers!) only one of these conditions will be true, so you don't actually need to check both of them.

Example:

```
random_value = random.random() # random number in range [0.0,1.0)
if random_value < 0.7:
    pass #something happens 70% of the time
else:
    pass #something happens the other 30% of the time
```

Or more compactly:

```
if (random.random() < 0.7):
    pass #something happens 70% of the time
else:
    pass #something happens 30% of the time
```

Comment: Keep in mind the compact version will only work for if/else, elif will behave unpredictably since each call to random will gen a new value.  Basics I know, but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you actually assigned something to `i`...

```
i = random.randint(1, 100)
```

And another thing: the `else` part is never, ever going to be executed. Every integer number is either <= 70 or >= 71, so the `else` will never be reached.

Comment: Whoops, disregard my previous comment. Anyway, the final `else` clause can only possibly be reached if `i` happens to be a floating point number in the range `(70.0-71.0)` - but since `i` is an integer, this will never happen and the final `else` clause will never be reached.